# Access table domain to list from non null table values

Tags: ms-access

Access noob here, Trying to better a legacy system as the new one may not be ready for a couple of years :/ .

I currently have a table "tblFees" that has community and fees/rates for types of development; not all communities have the same fee types.

I have a form where a user selects a community, and then selects a fee type.
I want that fee type drop down to be contextual, to only display applicable fee types.

tblFees: [image: tblFees]
I currently have all of those fee types (plus about 20 more) in a single column  "tblfeeType" table which is used in the drop down/combo box on the form.

So far I query by community and get a community name and a list of fees, How do I make it return the non-null field names in a list that can be used in my fee type combo box?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thnx

Comment: tblFees is not a normalized structure. Normalize it and you can easily restricted combobox list to only show fees associated with selected community. A UNION query can rearrange fields to normalized structure.